# Updating Canvas Shape With Range Slider Using EaselJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

How would I redraw a canvas shape while updating an object's properties, with EaselJS?  I see that the properties are being updating, but my draw function is not clearing the canvas or redrawing the shape with the new values.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z7e176t/1/)

HTML

```
<canvas id="example" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<div>
  <label>Width Size</label>
  <input type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="300" step="5" value="300" data-var="width">
</div>

<div>
  <label>Height Size</label>
  <input type="range" class="slider" min="0" max="300" step="5" value="5" data-var="height">
</div>
```

JS

```
stage = new createjs.Stage("example");

var canvasObject = {
    width: 300,
  height: 5
}

var rect = new createjs.Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(0, 0, canvasObject.width, canvasObject.height);

function draw() {
    stage.clear();

    stage.addChild(rect);

    stage.update();
}

$('.slider').on("input", function() { 
    canvasObject[$(this).data("var")] = $(this).val();    
    draw();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to redraw your rectangle once the value changes, or you can use the command approach to modify its properties once it has been changed.

```
var rect = new createjs.Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill("#000").drawRect(0, 0, canvasObject.width, canvasObject.height);

// Store the last command (the drawRect)
var rectCommand = rect.command;

// On Change, update the command
rectCommand.w = canvasObject.width;
rectCommand.h = canvasObject.height;

// Remember to update the stage when things change
stage.update();
```

You can see info about commands [here](http://blog.createjs.com/new-command-approach-to-easeljs-graphics/), and the command docs [here](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Rect.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is touching on what Lanny mentioned.  Simply remove the rectangle inside of the draw function, and redraw.

```
function draw() {

  stage.removeChild(rect);
  rect = new createjs.Shape();

  rect.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawRect(0, 0, canvasObject.width, canvasObject.height);

  stage.clear();

  stage.addChild(rect);

  stage.update();
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6z7e176t/9/)